# Button text SPANNABLE not applied

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using SpannableStringBuilder to apply to different style for a text in Button. But it is not applied.

```
SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder
    = new SpannableStringBuilder(valueText);
spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(
    new TextAppearanceSpan(mContext, R.style.ListItemButtonTitleTheme),
    0, 5, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
);
spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(
    new TextAppearanceSpan(mContext, R.style.ListItemButtonValueTheme),
    6, valueText.length() - 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
);
holder.valueButton.setText(
    spannableStringBuilder.toString(), Button.BufferType.SPANNABLE
);
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/value_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:0.7"
    style="@style/ListItemButtonTheme"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/hr_line_2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/type_button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/sell_button"
    android:text="Google" />
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="ListItemButtonTitleTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/list_item_content_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
    <item name="font">@font/proxima_nova_semibold</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>

<style name="ListItemButtonValueTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="font">@font/proxima_nova_semibold</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I had update my answer this is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use AppCompactButton instead of Button

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/value_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:0.7"
        style="@style/ListItemButtonTheme"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/hr_line_2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/type_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/sell_button"
        android:text="Google"
        />
```

and change spannable  to Spanned

```
  SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(valueText);
  spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(mContext, R.style.ListItemButtonTitleTheme), 0, 5, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
  spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(mContext, R.style.ListItemButtonValueTheme), 6, valueText.length()-1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
  holder.valueButton.setText(spannableStringBuilder.toString(), Button.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```